# ArrayList.Add - adds just references?

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am unable to find on MSDN so I am trying here again :) When adding element, its boxed and the reference to new object is added to the collection (if it is value type) or if the element is reference type, just reference is added to arraylist. Is that correct?

EDIT: So it contains just instances of Object class where each one references the value on the heap<

Answer (score 3):

That is correct.

In real code, however, you should use generic `List<T>`s instead of `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct.

ArrayList is not generic (it is from Fx 1.1) and has members like

```
void Add(System.Object item)  { ... }
```

So anytime you call `Add(x)`, `x` has to be converted to a `System.Object` typed reference. A trivial up-cast for any object reference but Boxing is needed for a value type.

And to join the majority here: You should (almost) never use it anymore. It's only for code that begun before 2005 and maybe for some very rare situation where you want to store mixed types.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Thanks. What I am unsure about: every value passed is also converted to System.Object reference..that means there will be new instance of Object?

Comment: @lojo: Yes, boxing means instantiating an object. And the ref is stored in the list.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: And what if its reference type value? So then it also creates new object which will point to the same location as the original reference type?

Comment: @Lojol: A reference type is already an object.  Therefore, it can just insert the reference as-is.

Comment: When `x` is a reference, no object is created. The content ( a reference) of `x` is copied into the ArrayList.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I do not get it. If I add reference type to arrayList, the reference is added..also there has to be some new object?

Comment: No, it's a reference to the same (old) object.

Comment: Well, so I can think of ArrayList as a list for types Object - also when I add new reference type value to arraylist, into this internal list is just added reference to the original value?

Comment: @Lojol: Yes, Try to find some articles with pictures, they're worth a 1000 words in these matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is correct.

List<> works differently, however.

Comment: To be clear: It works different for Value types, but the same for References.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct but you should not use ArrayList anyway and stick to generics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, just add a reference.

This is called shallow copy reference. In your case, you must implement a deep copy so you can create a new object and copy your value to it.