# list of array of strings in c#, how to properly use the add method

Tags: c#, string, list

I don't get why this code's output is :

```
34
34
```

```
List<String[]> list = new List<String[]>();
String[] s = new String[2];

s[0] = "1";
s[1] = "2";

list.Add(s);

s[0] = "3";
s[1] = "4";

list.Add(s);

foreach (String[] match in list)
    Console.WriteLine(match[0] + match[1]);
```

I think my code is fine to get the output of

```
12
34
```

Can someone help?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx

Comment: also, http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Because you are printing the same array twice. Arrays are reference types.

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775086/none-static-nested-class-inside-static-class-c-sharp) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696448/how-to-make-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843958/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-reference-type) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698361/cloning-a-reference-type) ...

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275251/how-save-array-in-list-by-value-not-reference-in-c-sharp) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157588/objects-in-listt-reference-same-value) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899129/how-to-add-an-array-to-a-list-by-value-not-by-reference) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736947/arraylist-add-adds-just-references) ...

Comment: When the site asks you to check whether your problem has been discussed before, **please do so**. SO is most useful if all the knowledge on every single problem is gathered in *one* question.

Comment: Would you expect the output to be "1 2" if you wrote `string s = "1"; s = "2"; Console.WriteLine(s); Console.WriteLine(s);`?

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the same `string` array to the list twice. You are only changing the internal values of the array.

You have to initialize a new array to put the new values in:

```
String[] s = new String[2];

s[0] = "1";
s[1] = "2";

list.Add(s);

s = new String[2]; // initialize new array
s[0] = "3";
s[1] = "4";

list.Add(s);
```

Comment: Or use a different variable, like `s1`, and `s2`. Personal preference though.

Comment: That may indeed be clearer, but there is no real need to.

Comment: or `list.Add(new[]{ "1", "2"});` (since there is no need to use variables in the first place)

Comment: @Default: I think for a novice user this might me too much.

Comment: I think some people think it's a good idea to [downvote answers to closed questions, more so for duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265165/372643),

Comment: @remundo: need more help? If not, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked most.

Answer (score 2):

An array is a reference type. The list contains the same references as array s. So the both elements of the list are the same references as s. As the last value of s is { "3", "4" } then you get the result as is.

Try the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListOfArrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

            list.Add( new string[] { "1", "2" } );
            list.Add( new string[] { "3", "4" } );

            foreach (string[] match in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match[0] + match[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
12
34
```

Take into account that it is better to use type name `string` instead of `String` The last is dependent of using directive.